# Design Pattern for toolbar

Tags: design-patterns

I would like to know which design pattern applies to implementing toolbars with many items (hierarchical toolbars).

I'm developing a Photoshop-like application with many tool combinations (tool selected with/without ctrl key pressed, etc) and before building a mess I ask here for a patter to solve this problem.

Leonardo.

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated the language or UI environment. In general though you should design the menu system separately from the (editing) commands that you need to execute.

When dealing with commands the Command Pattern provides mechanisms to hook individual commands to menu items and also addresses how to implement n-level undo and redo. The Command Pattern is a must for this part. You can get all this working without even considering the menu system.

You can probably find lots of tools/libraries in your chosen language that will help construct a menu system.

Linking the menu selections to the correct command will be easy. The general idea is that each menu item has a function doCommand() but all it does is delegate to the linked command's doCommand() which does what you want!

General question - general reply.